# Django model audit mixin

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

Hello I wanted to know how to create a few fields and convert them into a mixin.

Let's say I have the following.

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='%(class)s_created_by')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='%(class)s_modified_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created_date = timezone.now()
        self.modified_date = timezone.now()
        return super(Supplier, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I want to create a mixin to avoid writing every time the last 4 fields into different models.

Here is the mixin I would create:

```
class AuditMixin(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='%(class)s_created_by')
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='%(class)s_modified_by')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField()


   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if not self.id:
           self.created_date = timezone.now()
       self.modified_date = timezone.now()
       return super(Supplier, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class Supplier(AuditMixin):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=128)
```

How can I make sure that the related_name is relevant to the class the mixin is included into? Also in the save function, How can I make sure the class the mixin is included into is returned (as per the last line)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in any `super` call, you must **always** use the current class. So it will always be `super(AuditMixin, self)...` and your question does not apply.

Django itself takes care of substituting the current class name in `related_name` if you use the `%(class)s` syntax, which you have, so again there is nothing else for you to do. See [the model inheritance docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name-and-related-query-name).